# Codeigniter Email Confirmations

Tags: php, codeigniter

I m new in **Codeigniter**. I want to create a login & registration page in my project. Login and register is success but if i want to confirm email it always say **404 not found** if click the verify link. whats wrong with this code. Help me

Thanks

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Voter_model extends CI_Model
{


 function __construct()
 {
      // Call the Model constructor
      parent::__construct();
 }

 //get the username & password from tbl_usrs
 function get_user($username, $password)
 {
      $sql = "select * from user where username = '" . $username . "' and password = '" . $password . "' and status = '1'";
      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      return $query->num_rows();
 }


 //insert into user table
function insertUser($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
}

//send verification email to user's email id
function sendEmail($to_email)
{
    $from_email = ''; //change this to yours
    $subject = 'Aktivasi Akun';
    $message = 'Dear'. $username .'<br /><br />Please click on the below activation link to verify your email address.<br /><br /> 
  '. site_url('voter/voter_register/verify') . md5($to_email) . '<br /><br /><br />Thanks<br />Admin, Gus bala';

    //configure email settings
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'; //smtp host name
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465'; //smtp port number
    $config['smtp_user'] = $from_email;
    $config['smtp_pass'] = ''; //$from_email password
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    //send mail
    $this->email->from($from_email, 'Admin Evoting');
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    return $this->email->send();
}

//activate user account
function verifyEmailID($key)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $data = array('status' => 1);

    $this->db->where(md5('email'), $key);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);
}

}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is minor issue in your code.

Assume your `md5($to_email)` is equal to `15253545`. And in your mail sent this number via mail like this `site_url('voter/voter_register/verify').md5($to_email)`.

So what you set is:

```
www.stackoverflow.com/oter/voter_register/verify15253545
```

There is no any function call like `verify15253545`. Because you are missing `/` on the URL. So fix is:

```
site_url('voter/voter_register/verify/').md5($to_email)
                                     ^ Missing / on here
```

Now your URL reach the verify and passed data to `$hash`.

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '0c83f57c786a0b4a39efab23731c7ebc' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `user` SET `status` = 1 WHERE `0c83f57c786a0b4a39efab23731c7ebc` = '6d6ed6fb6b990a099d67af6b1986916e'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/evotingcucukan/application/models/Voter_model.php

Line Number: 61

Comment: Link is fixed, but now i cant verify the email whats wrong again ? Please help me